# Declaring variable within a function

Tags: c++

```
int function(int a, int b){
    a = a*b;
    return(a);
}
```

This is a really stupid questions but, if i pass in 4 and 2.
Why doesnt the **a** need to be declared?

Comment: `a` is declared as parameter already, but you miss declaring `c` there.

Comment: The name `a` is available for use in the function body when it is an argument.

Comment: `int a` function argument is in itself a variable.

Comment: `int a` is a definition. And while we  are at it, you don't need or want the parentheses here: `return(c);` - just say `return c;`

Comment: Ok but if i pass in 4,2 a = 4*2 = 8
But the a passed in is 4...

Comment: ***Ok but if i pass in 4,2 a = 4*2 = 8 But the a passed in is 4...*** No problem with that. You are passing by value (meaning a copy). This copy exists only inside your function.

Comment: I do not quite understand how is declaring `a` or not is related to 4 and 2?

Comment: I think the question would have been better if you added a minimal int `main();` that calls your function.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: "Ok but if i pass in 4,2 a = 4*2 = 8 But the a passed in is 4..." you are writing program not an algebra expressions. `a = a * b;` is not an equation but instruction which says "calculate a * b and store result to variable a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int function(int a, int b){ // two variables, a and b, are declared and set equal to whatever you passed in when you called the function.
    a = a*b; // now you are using the two already-declared variables
    return(a); // return the value of 'a' which was declared in the first line and then modified
}
```

Note that 'a' and 'b' in the above example are now destroyed. They only live inside of the function and are re-created every time you call function() with new values passed in. You can't call the 'a' and 'b' you were using in this function anywhere outside of this function, because they doesn't exist outside of this function. This means that you can declare another 'int a' and 'int b' outside of this function.

If I call this function in main:

```
int oldA = 5; // declare an int called oldA and set it to 5
int oldB = 10; // declare an int called oldB and set it to 10
cout << function(oldA, oldB); // makes a copy of oldA and oldB and then uses them inside function()
// note that oldA and oldB are still 5 and 10. A copy of them was made and then 
// used inside of function.
```